# Create document index of word positions

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

**Problem:**

I want to perform indexing by creating a data structure in python that will store all the words from a given text file and will also store its line numbers (all the lines in which those words appear) and also the position of the word (column #) in that particular line.

So far I am able to store the words in the dictionary by appending all the line numbers in a list but I am not able to store their positions in that particular line.

I need this data structure for faster searching of text files.

**Here's my code up till now:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
thetextfile = open('file.txt','r')
thetextfile = thetextfile.read()
file_s = thetextfile.split("\n")
wordlist = defaultdict(list)
lineNumber = 0
for (i,line) in enumerate(file_s):

    lineNumber = i
    for word in line.split(" "):
       wordlist[word].append(lineNumber)

print(wordlist)
```

Comment: what is the format of your text file?

Comment: @Leonid , It can be of any format.

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo , I am newbie to python, I am not able to proceed well.

Comment: @KiaraSingh , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited my question, I guess now it should be clear.

Comment: `entry[0]` *is* the first word.  If that's not what you want, why do you use that?  You'll need to loop over the output from `split` to create one datum for each word.

Comment: If a word exists on multiple lines, you will only keep the last one.  If that's suitable, maybe update the question to say so.  If not, maybe edit your question to explain what end result you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to store the line numbers and columns of the words in your text document:

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple

# build a named tuple for the word locations
Location = namedtuple('Location', 'line col')

# dict keyd by word in document
word_locations = defaultdict(list)

# go through each line in the document
for line_num, line in enumerate(open('my_words.txt', 'r').readlines()):
    column = -1
    prev_col = 0

    # process the line, one word at a time
    while True:   
        if prev_col < column:
            word = line[prev_col:column]
            word_locations[word].append(Location(line_num, prev_col))
        prev_col = column+1

        # find the next space
        column = line.find(' ', prev_col)

        # check for more spaces on the line
        if column == -1:

            # there are no more spaces on the line, store the last word
            word = line[prev_col:column]
            word_locations[word].append(Location(line_num, prev_col))

            # go onto the next line
            break

print(word_locations)
```